# Project is targeting runtime 'win7-x64' but did not resolve any runtime-specific packages for the 'Microsoft.NETCore.App' package

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I am trying to deploy stateless micro service application into service fabric but I get this error as soon as I start the deployment.

Project is targeting runtime 'win7-x64' but did not resolve any runtime-specific packages for the 'Microsoft.NETCore.App' package. This runtime may not be supported by .NET Core.

How to fix this ?

Comment: What is your target framework version of your project? Please try to share your pubxml file with us?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 5):

If you're unable to upgrade to .NET Core 3.1, you can suppress this error by adding this inside a `<PropertyGroup>` in your project file:

```
<EnsureNETCoreAppRuntime>false</EnsureNETCoreAppRuntime>
```

The error is a design-time error and won't cause a runtime failure.

Answer (score 2):

If you create your stateless micro service application on VS2019, you should note that `Net Core <=3.0` is not supported by Stateless project.

So you should target your project framework to at least `Net Core 3.1`.

Right-click on your project **Properties**-->**Application**-->change target framework version to `net core 3.1`.

[image]

If I target project into net core 2.2, the error will happen.

[image]

**Note that**, you should make sure that your target framework version of the `pubxml` file is the same of your project target framework version.

[image]